# Application of the Hahn-Banach Theorem from Folland

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm struggling to understand the following proof of the theorem stated in Folland (p. 159).

> 5.8 Thm
> Let $X$ be a normed vector space.
>
> If $M$ is a closed subspace of X and $x\in X\backslash M$, there exists $f\in L(X,K)$ such that $f(x)\neq0$ and $f|M=0.$ In fact, if $\delta=inf_{y\in M} ||x-y||, f $ can be taken to satisfy $||f||=1$ and $f(x)=\delta$
>
> Pf: Define $f$ on $M+\mathbb{C}x$ by $f(y+\lambda x)=\lambda \delta (y\in M, \lambda\in \mathbb{C}).$ Then $f(x)=\delta, f|M=0,$ and for $\lambda\neq 0, |f(y+\lambda x)|=|\lambda|\delta\leq|\lambda|||\lambda ^{-1}y+x||=||y+\lambda x||$. Then you can apply the Hahn-Banach Thm.

What I really can't understand is the the last inequality $|\lambda|\delta\leq|\lambda|||\lambda ^{-1}y+x||$.
We define $\delta$ to be $\delta=inf_{y\in M}||x-y||$ so I get
$$|\lambda|\delta\leq|\lambda|||x-y||.$$
How do I go from here to the desired inequality? Or do I have to take a different route?

Thank you for reading.
I would deeply appreciate any comment.

Comment: The two $y$ denote different things there. Write $\delta = \inf \{ \lVert x-z\rVert : z \in M\}$. Then consider $w = \lambda^{-1}y$. Since $y\in M$, we have $w\in M$. Hence, $\lVert x-w\rVert \geqslant \delta$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you. I'm starting to get it. Can I ask one more? Can we say $||x-w||\leq||x+w||$? If so, how?

Comment: No, that doesn't necessarily hold. And I didn't quite pay attention, consider $w = -\lambda^{-1}y$ rather than $\lambda^{-1}y$. Then $x-w = x+\lambda^{-1}y$ and all looks as it should.

Comment: @DanielFischer Now I get it completely. Thank you.

Comment: @DanielFischer Is the $\mathcal{M}+\mathbb{C}x$ there as a translation of the input?